# Statistics Homework Question

Tags: statistics

I tried to got my my TA's office hours today but someone hogged him for 45 minutes and I didn't get a chance to ask my question. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me.
Note that this is a question about diagnosing people with a disease
$P(D)$ is the probability the person has the disease.

*Assume that for a randomly selected person, $P(D) = 0.2$, $P(\text{Positive test}\mid D) = 1$. $P(\text{Positive test}\mid\overline{D}) = 0.05$, so that the inexpensive test only gives false positive, and not false negative results.*

*Suppose that this inexpensive test costs $\$10$. If a person tests positive then they are also given a more expensive test costing $\$100$, which correctly identifies all persons with the disease. What is the expected cost per person if a population is tested for the disease using the inexpensive test followed, if necessary, by the expensive test?*

Comment: You say $0.2$, but the answer in the back of your book is right if it's $0.02$.  See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
& & & & & \bullet \\[15pt]
& & & & \swarrow0.2 & & \searrow0.8 \\[15pt]
& & & D & & & & \overline{D} \\[15pt]
& & & & & & \swarrow & & \searrow \\[15pt]
& & & & & & \text{positive} & & \text{negative} \\[15pt]
& & & & & \swarrow & & \searrow \\[15pt]
& & & & D & & & & \overline{D}
\end{array}
$$
Follow this tree.  Everybody pays $\$10$ for the first test.

Then $5\%$ of the aformentioned $80\%$ of the population pays $\$100$ for the second test.

The $20\%$ who are ill also pay the $\$100$ for the second test.

So
$$
\$10 + (0.2)\$100 + (0.05)(0.8)\$100 = \$10 + \$4 = \$34.
$$

Another p.o.v.: You have $100$ people.  Of those, $20$ are ill.  They take both tests, paying $\$110$ each.  Of the other $80$ people, $5\%$ take both tests, paying $\$110$.  That's $4$ people.  They other $76$ test negative on the cheap test, and pay only $\$10$ each.  So
$$
24\cdot\$110 + 76\cdot\$10 = \$3400.
$$
So the average is $\$34$.

Later note: You say the answer at the end of the book is $\$16.90$.  That would be correct if $P(D)=0.02$ rather than $0.2$.  Just go through the above with those numbers instead of what we used.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to me, the only thing is that they are giving an answer of $16.90 at the end of the book... Do you have any idea how they are coming to that answer?

Comment: I deleted this answer, then edited further, then un-deleted it.  I initially omitted the fact that everyone who is ill also takes the second test.

Comment: If $\$16.90$ is given as the answer, it's got to be a weighted average of $\$110$ and $\$10$ for some weights, say $w$ and $1-w$.  So $110w+10(1-w)=16.90$.  That says $100w + 10=16.90$, so $100w=6.9$, and $w=0.069$.  That would mean only $6.9\%$ of the population take the second test.  To me that makes no sense, since all of the $20\%$ who are ill would take the second test.

Comment: OK, here's the bottom line: if $P(D)=0.02$, i.e. $2\%$ rather than $20\%$ have the disease, then the answer is $\$16.90$.

Comment: Michael Thank you soooo much for your help, I apologize for misreading the question, I even used 0.2 when I was working in my note book. As it turns out... P(D)=0.02 like you suspected. Sorry for the misunderstanding on my part and thank you for the helpful explanation!!!

Answer (score 0):

Draw yourself a [probability tree](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/images/figure_89.gif). On the first fork we have $P(D) = 0.2$ and $P(D') = 0.8$. On the second set of forks we have $P(+|D) = 1$, $P(-|D) = 0$, $P(+|D')=0.05$ and $P(-|D') = 0.95$. It follows that $P(+ \wedge D) = 0.2 \times 1 = 0.2$, $P(- \wedge D) = 0.2 \times 0 = 0$, $P(+ \wedge D') = 0.8 \times 0.05 = 0.04$, and $P(- \wedge D') = 0.8 \times 0.95 = 0.76$.

The [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) can be found by multiplying the probability by the cost. I get

$$E[X] = 0.2 \times 110 + 0 \times 10 + 0.04 \times 110 + 0.76 \times 10 = 34 \, .$$

Thus, you can expect to pay 34 dollars per person.